# Remove trailing char when congregating after merging text in multiple columns to one

Tags: arrays, regex, if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm trying to congregate text in multiple columns into one column in google sheets.  I'm using the following formula.  It works but unless there is an item in column E I get a comma at the end of any entry that was in B,C, or D.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(G:G)=1,"Events", IF(A:A="","", B:B) & IF(B:B<>"",", "&C:C, C:C) & IF(C:C<>"",", "&D:D, D:D) & IF(D:D<>"",", "&E:E, E:E)))
```

How to I check to see if there are no entries after and thus remove the trailing comma.

For exmaple, this works:

```
event1, event2, event3, event 4
```

but if there is not an item in the last column (E) then it looks like this

```
event1, event2,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(IF(ROW(G:G)=1, "Events", 
 IF(A:A="",, B:B)& 
 IF(B:B<>"", ", "&C:C, C:C)& 
 IF(C:C<>"", ", "&D:D, D:D)& 
 IF(D:D<>"", ", "&E:E, E:E))), ",$", ))
```